# Middleware function doesnt exist

Tags: php, laravel

In my web.php I have a route

```
Route::get('summary_average_fee', 'Summary@AverageFee')->middleware('CheckParams@dateLimits');
```

Im trying to refrence the dateLimits function in the CheckParams class

My CheckParams class, saved as CheckParams.php in the Middleware folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckParams
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function dateLimits($request, Closure $next)
    {
        isEmpty($request->input('startDate'), 'NO_START_DATE');
        isEmpty($request->input('endDate'), 'NO_END_DATE');

        return $next($request);
    }

    private function isEmpty($value, $error, $status)
    {
        if(empty($value))
        {
            return response()->json($error, 422);
        }
    }
}
```

In the kernal.php file I add this to the routeMiddleware array

```
'CheckParams' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckParams::class
```

When it runs, I get the error that Class CheckParams@dateLimits does not exist

Comment: Did you see somewhere that Laravel supports multiple methods in a middleware class?

Comment: That's not how it works. Each middleware should be a class. You can't target a function inside a class. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

Comment: Your middleware also wouldn't work since the response from isEmpty is ignored.

Comment: I just assumed it did, so dateLimits has to be the class then? with no function

Comment: @BilalAhmed It's not the same problem.

Comment: @Devon I thought it would return the response and that would be the end of that

Comment: @WillDaniels usually it helps to read the docs, not sure why you'd make this assumption

Comment: No, returning from isEmpty has no bearing on the return value of handle.

Comment: Ok, i could add a global variable and set it to false if the empty function runs, then only return next if its true in the handle

Comment: Do you mean a class property?  I wouldn't use a global here.

Comment: Yeh i meant that, a variable inside the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that your middleware should be rewritten and update the usage:

```
use App\Http\Middleware\CheckParams;

Route::get('summary_average_fee', 'Summary@AverageFee')->middleware(CheckParams::class);
```

Middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckParams
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $this->isEmpty($request->input('startDate'), 'NO_START_DATE');
        $this->isEmpty($request->input('endDate'), 'NO_END_DATE');

        return $next($request);
    }

    private function isEmpty($value, $error, $status)
    {
        if(empty($value))
        {
            return response()->json($error, 422);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Didnt realise you couldnt call functions in middleware

Comment: Try to use artisan commands when possible, for middleware creation: `php artisan make:middleware MyMiddleware`